# Databe connection error on start

Tags: php, database, phalcon

I am having problems with a connection to the database, specifically, when I try to access the system and the database does not respond.

I am getting an error in my services.php file.

And this is the code:

```
     try{
$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
    $config = $config->get('database')->toArray();
    $dbClass = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $config['adapter'];
    if (stripos($config['adapter'], 'Mysql')!== false) {
        $mi_conf = array(
            "host" => $config['host'],
            "username" => $config['username'],
            "password" => $config['password'],
            "dbname" => $config['dbname'],
            "options" => array(
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
            )
        );      
    } else {
        $mi_conf = array(
            "dbname" => '//'.$config['host'].'/'.$config['dbname'],
            "username" => $config['username'],
            "password" => $config['password'],
            'charset' => 'utf8'
        );
    }

    unset($config['adapter']);

    return new $dbClass($mi_conf);
});
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     $error .= 'db, ';
     return null;
 }
```

I do not know if it will be necessary to change there or I have to make changes to each call from each model.

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: connection timeout. The database was offline, I switch on again, but, I want to catch this error. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks without errors.
Use setShared to avoid connecting to the database multiple times, or use the "persistent" attribute on the configuration to take effect. Maybe it does the trick. By the way, change the try catch to the moment where the service was created, so you can catch the exception.

```
        $di->setShared('db', function () use ($config) {
try {
            $config  = $config->get('database')->toArray();
            $dbClass = 'Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\\' . $config['adapter'];
            if (stripos($config['adapter'], 'Mysql') !== false) {
                $mi_conf = array(
                    "host"     => $config['host'],
                    "username" => $config['username'],
                    "password" => $config['password'],
                    "dbname"   => $config['dbname'],
                    "persistent" => false,
                    "options"  => array(
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
                    ),
                );
            } else {
                $mi_conf = array(
                    "dbname"   => '//' . $config['host'] . '/' . $config['dbname'],
                    "username" => $config['username'],
                    "password" => $config['password'],
                    "persistent" => false,
                    'charset'  => 'utf8',
                );
            }

            unset($config['adapter']);

            return new $dbClass($mi_conf);
} catch (Exception $e) {
        $error .= 'db, ';
        return null;
    }
        });
```